# Keep the values in page when navigating to other pages

Tags: vb.net, xaml, uwp

I am developing a UWP app where there is a "page" and in that page, there are several "textbox"es which values are entered by a user (numbers). When it is navigated to other pages to take other values and came back to this page the values entered in "textbox"es are all lost. I used "NavigationCacheMode", no success.

Could you please help how to maintain values in UI elements (textboxes) in current page when navigating to other pages.

I would appreciate if the solution were in VB.NET.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to save the date by yourself in this scenario. For example, you could choose the [ApplicationData.LocalSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings) to save the data when navigating to other page.

You could save the data on the page's OnNavigatedFrom method and get the data in its OnNavigatedTo method like the following:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox1"></TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox2"></TextBox>
    <Button Content="navigate" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

```
Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
Inherits Page
Dim localSettings As Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As NavigationEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnNavigatedTo(e)
    Dim value1 As Object = localSettings.Values(textbox1.Name)
    Dim value2 As Object = localSettings.Values(textbox2.Name)

    If value1 IsNot Nothing And value2 IsNot Nothing Then
        textbox1.Text = value1.ToString()
        textbox2.Text = value2.ToString()
    End If

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedFrom(e As NavigationEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnNavigatedFrom(e)
    localSettings.Values(textbox1.Name) = textbox1.Text
    localSettings.Values(textbox2.Name) = textbox2.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Frame.Navigate(GetType(BlankPage1))
End Sub
```

End Class